# Permissions aren't in sync in Chrome web extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-web-store

In my chrome extension I use `"activeTab"` and `"*://*.example.com/*"` (API) as permissions.

In the options popup, I get the following warnings:

- Replace the page you see when opening a new tab
- Communicate with cooperating websites

However, when I install the extension I get an extra one "Can read and change all website data".

Does anyone know where does this extra warning come from?

Comment: Always provide a full [MCVE](/help/mcve) in your questions - in questions about extensions including the entire manifest.json is usually a must. You probably declared a content script on all URLs. It indeed gives your extension the ability to access all sites even without opening them in a tab (e.g. using an iframe).

Comment: @wOxxOm indeed, I have a content script on all pages, but, do you know if there is a documentation that states that such case adds and extra permission?

Comment: Well, this is how it always worked. [This page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions#type-Permissions) mentions both "permissions" and "content_scripts" hosts. There may be other pages.

Comment: @wOxxOm if I declare "http://*/" and "https://*/" as an optional permissions, will I get the warning "Can read and change all website data" after installing the extension?

Comment: Warnings are displayed for "permissions" and "content_scripts".

Comment: @wOxxOm is there a way to have a content script running on all pages, but without a warning "Can read and change all website data"?

Comment: You can use `optional_permissions` and `declarativeContent` API (see the demo extensions) so no warning will be shown during the installation, but then you'll need to request the permissions from the user manually so in the end it'll be the same.